# Should I store a dataframe in Flask cache or session?

Tags: flask, flask-caching

My flask app pulls user data from an external API and does a small amount of processing and generates a dataframe.  Although not really heavy there is a noticeable delay in loading the data onto a page.  This same data is used by several pages on the app to display different aspects of the data.  In order to speed things up I thought about saving the data temporarily (10 mins or so) and reusing this rather than grabbing the data on each page load.

A simplified function to gather the data is:

```
def get_dataset_from_wahoo(per_page=300, page=1):
    connection = Connection.query.filter_by(user_id = current_user.id, provider = 'wahoo')
    if connection.count() == 0:  #does not exist - return to index and point to auth page
        return render_template('home/index_noauth.html', title='Authentication Error')

    #return a valid token object from the database
    token = connection.first().token
    expires = token['created_at'] + token['expires_in']
    now = int(datetime.now().strftime("%s"))
    if now > expires:   #token has expired, get a new one
        token = refresh_token(token)
        connection.one().token = token
        db.session.commit()

    #request the data using the valid token
    header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']}
    param = {'per_page': per_page, 'page': page}
    dataset = requests.get(api_url + '/workouts', headers=header, params=param).json()

    #create a dataframe from the returned dataset
    df = pd.json_normalize(dataset['workouts'])
    for col in df:
        df[col]=pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='ignore')
    for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
        df[col]=pd.to_datetime(df[col], errors='ignore')
    return df
```

I can cache this result using Flask-Caching memoize and this seems to speed things up.  I am unclear how the filesystem cache is cleared though?  Do I just have to run a clean up task on the server?  Or would a better approach be to store the dataframe in a Flask-session (it has a maximum size of around 200kB from my initial testing)?

Any advice is appreciated as i am quite new to flask.

Martyn